# what's the most efficient way to append elements in IE8+?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a complex webpage which has a lot of elements which are heavily manipulated.
While this runs quite smoothly on Chrome/FF, IE (8 + 9) seem to freeze over quite often on this page.

One specific section of the code which runs incredibly slower on IE than it does on other browsers is where i append new elements to the page: Specifically, I have 50 (nested) elements which I append to a documentFragment, and then eventually I append the documentFragment to some element in the actual document. This last append happens v. fast on Chrome/FF, but can take more than a few seconds in IE.

I tried using html() / innerHTML, which only seemed to make matters worse (they might be better than append()-ing the elements one by one, but the documentFragment does seem to help). Question is, what can I do about it? Is there some more efficient way I could insert these elements in IE? Am I missing something which could cause them to be inserted so slowly?

Thanks.

**== EDIT ==**

Code example (not 1:1 but this is what i was referring to in general):

```
function insertContent(elementsCollection)
{
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (var i=0; i < elementsCollection.length; i++)
    {
        fragment.appendChild($(collection[i])[0]);
    }

    $("#parentDiv").append(fragment);
}
```

Comment: If you post some code examples it would be a lot easier to try and figure out what is going on.

Comment: Is it the insertion or is it the redrawing of the layout that is the problem? If you insert it into an element that has `display: none` does it still go as slowly? The reason I ask is because I know that in the past at least IE has been pretty slow at rendering things at a deep nesting level in terms of tables, etc. so I am wondering if that is where the problems are...

Answer (score 0):

I always used (and recommend)

```
rootNode.replaceChild(newElement, oldElement)
```

I did not face problems like you mentioned in IE/FF/Chrome/Safari. I prepare the new document fragment in isolation and replace the existing node with the new in one go, rather than building the active DOM tree node at a time.